# partial applied function works only for the first time.

Tags: javascript

I have defined my own version of `partial` function:

```
const partial = function (fn,...partialArgs){
  let args = partialArgs;
  return function(...fullArguments) {
    let arg = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length && arg < fullArguments.length; i++) {
      if (args[i] === undefined) {
        args[i] = fullArguments[arg++];
        }
      }
      return fn.apply(null, args);
  };
};
```

and when I use it:

```
let delay = partial(setTimeout,undefined,100)
delay(() => console.log("XXX"))
```

it does prints `XXX` as I expect. But when I try to reuse the function `delay`, it seems that it doesn't work:

```
delay(() => console.log("YYY"))
```

even the above code snippet prints `XXX`!! I'm not sure where I'm making the mistake.

Comment: Is it your intention to have `partial` replace `undefined` arguments in `partialArgs` with ones from `fullArguments`? That's a very unusual form of partial application, but I can see use cases...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yeah thats exactly what I was trying to do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you **modify** the `args` that you retain when the function is called; subsequent calls reuse the modified args because you're only filling in ones that have `undefined`.

If that's intentional (filling in holes), then you need to make a copy of `partialArgs` each time before modifying the copy, see `***` comments:

```js
const partial = function(fn, ...partialArgs) {
  // *** Not creating `args` here
  return function(...fullArguments) {
    let arg = 0;
    let args = partialArgs.slice(); // *** Make a copy here before modifying
    for (let i = 0; i < args.length && arg < fullArguments.length; i++) {
      if (args[i] === undefined) {
        args[i] = fullArguments[arg++];
      }
    }
    return fn.apply(null, args);
  };
};

let delay = partial(setTimeout, undefined, 100)

delay(() => console.log("XXX"))

delay(() => console.log("YYY"))
```

Comment: LGTM, __if__ statement could be simplified `args[i] = args[i] || fullArguments[arg++];`

Comment: My bad! I tried moving `args` inside the return function. But completely forgot that it uses the original reference!